# Shift rows to left

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df:

```
   A   B  C
1 10   11 23
2 NaN  2  15
3 NaN  3  31
4 NaN NaN 56
```

I want to shift the rows to the left to line up on the index as below:

```
  A   B   C
1 10  11  23
2 2   15  NaN
3 3   31  NaN
4 56  NaN NaN
```

I have been trying to write a function that I can apply to the rows of the df. I was thinking if `nan_counts = row.isnull().count()` I could use `shift(-Nan_counts,axis=1)` but I am having absolutely no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for row processing with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), 1)
print (df)
      0     1     2
1  10.0  11.0  23.0
2   2.0  15.0   NaN
3   3.0  31.0   NaN
4  56.0   NaN   NaN
```

For columns names (general solution):

```
print (df)
      A     B   C   D   E
1  10.0  11.0  23 NaN NaN
2   NaN   2.0  15 NaN NaN
3   NaN   3.0  31 NaN NaN
4   NaN   NaN  56 NaN NaN

df1 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), 1)
df1.columns = df.columns[:len(df1.columns)]
df1 = df1.reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df1)
      A     B     C   D   E
1  10.0  11.0  23.0 NaN NaN
2   2.0  15.0   NaN NaN NaN
3   3.0  31.0   NaN NaN NaN
4  56.0   NaN   NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Nice solution.
Note: 'reindex_axis' has been deprecated. Use 'reindex' instead.

Answer (score 1):

For each row, use a list comprehension to keep only non-nan values and convert it as a Series. Pandas will automatically fill missing values with nan when the Serieses are combined.

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([e for e in x if pd.notnull(e)]), axis=1)
Out[27]: 
      0     1     2
1  10.0  11.0  23.0
2   2.0  15.0   NaN
3   3.0  31.0   NaN
4  56.0   NaN   NaN
```